# ATMega328P receiver and transmitter pins

Tags: atmega328

I am trying to connect Bluetooth, GSM and GPS to the ATMega328P, but since it has only 1 RX and 1 TX, can I use the digital pins of ATMega328P as RX/TX pins.

Comment: Look up SoftwareSerial.

Comment: you have not done any research, have you?

Comment: a little bit but that time i was not able to come up with a solution.Now i have the solution

Comment: The ATmega328p is not a good match for projects needing this level of connectivity - it can be done, but only by a lot of software juggling.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after the [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library.

> The SoftwareSerial library has been developed to allow serial communication on other digital pins of the Arduino, using software to replicate the functionality (hence the name "SoftwareSerial"). It is possible to have multiple software serial ports with speeds up to 115200 bps. A parameter enables inverted signaling for devices which require that protocol.

Although, SoftwareSerial does come with limitations. The major one is that only one serial port can receive data at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need something with 4 hardware serial ports. 2560 processor.

Comment: Or an ARM part compatible with Arduino usage...

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoftwareSerial as mentioned above, and just wire the TX/RX to the desired digital pins. You will have to enable and disable the serial ports when you want to read/write to a specific port (Bluetooth/GSM), but that is not terribly difficult. I wrote a blog post on SoftwareSerial with an HM-10 Bluetooth module - there you can see how I wired and coded the SoftwareSerial via digital pins.

[Arduino IoT with Bluetooth](https://engineersportal.com/blog/2018/3/21/arduino-internet-of-things-part-2-lowering-the-power-consumption-of-the-atmega328p-breadboard-arduino-with-the-hm-10-bluetooth-module)